# Time/date link to PHP file when running in different URLs

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I presently have a situation whereby I need to show the new copy in a staging area for review in current time. On the live site this new copy needs to show on a set time and date in the future.

For example:
preview.webaddress.co.uk (staging area) to show new copy.
www.webaddress.co.uk (live area) not to show until said date and time.

This is how it looks at present:

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set("europe/london");
    $current_date = intval(date("YmdHi"));
    if(201701011000 < $current_date ) {
        ?>

        <?php include('new_copy_for_new_time_to_add.php');?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php include('existing_copy_which_stays.php');?>
```

Comment: where is the problem ?

Comment: any error in code?

Answer (score 0):

I've made amendments to above code and added more info to help.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know your problem.
but you need

delete final line

```
?>
```